# How validation Select Option with extra field ( --please select option--)

Tags: laravel

```
{!! Form::select('occupation', getOccupationStatus() , null, ["class" => 
      "form-control"])!!}
<small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</small>
```

How validation this field with please select option

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name to your select field ( *in your case it's occupation I think* ), then use Validation Rules as below

```
// Validation rules ...
$rules = [
    ...
    'occupation' => 'required',
    ...
];
```